# How to decompile with correct line numbers using fernflower?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, decompiling

I'm using `Intellij Idea 14` working with big java project where a lot of code is compiled and w/o sources.

As far as I know `Idea` can't make a search in compiled code (as `eclipse` does), but it can decompile single file using build-in `fernflower` and this also gives a possibility to debug through compiled code.

Is there a way to decompile all compiled code at once the same way Idea does and attach it to project so that it was possible to search through "Project and Libs" w/o loosing debugging feature in decompiled sources?

I've tried using `Bytecodeviewer` with different `fernflower` options, but the result was that debugging was broken (showed wrong lines) after attaching the decompiled sources.

Comment: I don't think any decompiler can perverse original line numbers. I'd be amazed if you can correctly debug with decompiled sources in Eclipse.

Comment: not sure about eclipse, but Intellij Idea does this magic. http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2015/02/debug-decompiled-code-with-intellij-idea-14-1/

Comment: That's actually pretty interesting, thanks @hahn.

Comment: @stiver some help here?

Answer (score 14):

I found that on OSX you can change this setting in the following file:

> ~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea2016.1/options/options.xml

Add the following properties:

```
    <property name="decompiler.use.line.mapping" value="true" />
    <property name="decompiler.dump.original.lines" value="true" />
```

Comment: or through Cmd + Shift + A -> Registry in Intellij

Comment: @hahn - Or just go to the Help Menu > Find Action > Registry. Then set "decompiler.dump.original.lines" to true.

Comment: In Windows, it is in: `%USERPROFILE%\.IdeaIC15\config\options\options.xml`; Shortcut in IntelliJ: `Ctrl + Shift + A` > `Registry`

Answer (score 2):

ok, as there are no news regarding this, I've created a little plugin which decompiles the jar file with compiled code to new `*-sources.jar` file using build-in `Intellij` `fernflower` decompiler and attaches sources to project. anyone interested, can take a look at `decompile and attach` plugin in jetbrains plugin repository

Update
answering my question about line numbers in decompiled code using `fernflower`. I found '`decompiler.use.line.table`' flag in `Intellij`'s `fernflower` which preserves line numbers.

Comment: Where is this flag? in which file?

Comment: @KilleKat this flag was either renamed. If you open Intellij's Registry you should be able to find keys containing "decompiler" word. In latest IDEA this is named as "decompiler.dump.original.lines" and "decompiler.use.line.mapping"

Comment: @Mafick - Please see hahn's comment in above answer or mine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using new pluing named **Quiltflower** then use '**Dump Original Lines**' option under

```
Tools ➡ Quiltflower
```

It will add a comment at the end of each line with an original line number.